# JSON Destination Component generating incorrect JSON

Tags: json, kingswaysoft

I cannot seem to get this component to generate the correct JSON.

I have followed the steps in this article to generate a batch request: https://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2021/04/28/Proper-Output-Handling-with-KingswaySoft-JSON-Destination-Component

I am passing rows into the component, and want to generate an object that looks like this, with the array filled with as many objects as the batch size:

```
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "fullAddress": "Text here"
    },
    {
      "fullAddress": "Text here"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have configured the component as follows:

[image]

The actual request being received on the server look as follows, with each subsequent object nested inside an array, and not added as a top level object to the sites array.

```
{
   "sites":[
      {
         "fullAddress":"Text here"
      },
      [
         {
            "fullAddress":"Text here"
         },
         [
            {
               "fullAddress":"Text here"
            }
         ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

I've tried a few different approaches and I either recieve errors that I am generating invalid json, or I end up in this situation. Any assitance appreciated!

UPDATE: Using the standard JSON Merge with the same settings works as expected. This means I just need to split the generating of the JSON and making the HTTP request, which is a shame